# How to Export High Res PNGS more Efficiently

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, png

I sell a bunch of my hand drawn art as individual elements and I'm trying to find a way to export my work more efficiently in Photoshop.

To start I take my Hand Drawn Elements from illustrator and copy & paste them to Photoshop as individual shapes.

When I create the document resolution is high res 300 ppi. When I create the PS document they're also 300 ppi. However when I try to right click and quick export them, or run the default script they come out 72 ppi.

I can manually create individual documents and paste them but with trimming transparency etc that's just way too time consuming. I'm sure I'm missing something. There just has to be a better way...

Comment: What is the resulting image size in pixels?

Comment: Why not export directly from illustrator?

Comment: Is there a quicker way to export them as png in illustrator? I am all for it! I sometimes have a 100 or more different elements. Is there a script that will run and save them all individually as 300 dpi png?

Answer (score 1):

Set up your document with multiple artboards, one for each illustration, with the appropriate about of blank space around each illustration. The artboards can all be different sizes.

Go to File > Export.

Select PNG from the `Format:` dropdown.

Select the `Use Artboards` check box underneath the format drop down.

Click `Export`.

The next window that pops up gives you options to change the resolution, anti-aliasing and transparency to your liking.

Click `OK`.

This will deliver you a separate PNG file for each artboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand your case. You have one drawing and you want to export several parts of this drawing, is it right?

You can quick create artboards for selected object or group of objects, and then just use Export -> Export All Artboards. In Illustrator off course.